# JavaScript generate an HTML <ul> list with <li> content in a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, modulo

I have a for-loop in javascript/jQuery to create an html unordered list. I want every multiple of 10 iteration to be a new unordered list tag.

JavaScript code:

```
var count = 100;
for(var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
        $('ul.list').append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
    } else {
        if(i % 10 == 0) {
            $('ul.list').after('<ul class="list"></ul>');
        }
        $('ul.list:last-child').append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
    }
}
```

It looks like it should work, but JavaScript generates this:

```
<ul class="list"><li>0</li></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
<ul class="list"></ul>
...
```

I expect it to output 10 `<li>` items and then create a new unordered list tag every 10th item.  Clearly the code is all wrong.  Can I get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be more inclined to build a string with the HTML, then post it one time.

Try ...

```
var max = 100;
var HTML = ["<ul class='list'>"];
for (var i=0,len=max; i<len; i++) {
  HTML.push("<li>" + i + "</li>");
  if (i%10===0 && (i!==0) {
    HTML.push("</ul>");
    HTML.push("<ul class='list'>");
  }
}
HTML.push("</ul>");

$("#lists").html(HTML.join("\n");
```

Basically, I've built an array of the html code needed, then merged it into one string with line breaks `\n` as I placed it into the DOM.

The `if` inside the loop closes the `<ul>` and opens a new one, but NOT on the zero (first step in the loop).